# Recurrence relation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A country uses as currency coins with values of 1 peso, 2pesos, 5 pesos, and 10 pesos and bills with values of 5 pesos, 10 pesos, 20 pesos, 50 pesos, and 100 pesos.

a) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to pay a bill of n pesos if the order in which the coins and bills are paid matters.

b) How many ways are there to pay a bill of 17 pesos, where the order in which coins and bills are paid matters ?

my try was :

when i pay $ n$ pesos i either

- pay 1 pesos coin , then n-1 pesos
- pay 2 pesos coin , then n-2 pesos if n $\ge$ 2
- pay 5 pesos coin , then n-5 pesos if n $\ge$ 5
- pay 10 pesos coin , then n-10 pesos if n $\ge$ 10
- pay 5 pesos bill , then n-5 pesos if n $\ge$ 5
- pay 10 pesos bill , then n-10 pesos if n $\ge$ 10
- pay 20 pesos bill , then n-20 pesos if n $\ge$ 20
- pay 50 pesos bill , then n-50 pesos if n $\ge$ 50
- pay 100 pesos bill , then n-100 pesos if n $\ge$ 100

$a_0 = 1$

so i have $ a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-5} + 2a_{n-10} + a_{n-20} + a_{n-50} + a_{n-100} $

I didn't get (b) right. so what's wrong with my solution ?

Comment: How would the order of the bills matter irl?

Comment: Looks good to me, what was your final answer on part b?

Comment: $ a_17 = a_{16} + a_{15} + 2a_{12} + 2a_{7} = 8158 $

Comment: how did you find a_16?

Comment: $ a_{16} = a_{15} + a_{14} + 2a_{11} + 2a_{6} = 5041 $

Comment: If someone wants to know why we can't pay n-1 pesos and then 1 pesos (The others are similar) after the above enumeration based on "if the order in which the coins and bills are paid matters" (This is my confusion when I met with this problem, searched and got here), it is that this has been contained in "pay $i$ pesos coin , then $n-i$ pesos" when $n-i=1$ and the later related iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Your recurrence relation is correct.
The answer  to (b) part is **9494**.

The following are the first 18 terms(0-17) :

1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 17 | 31 | 54 | 95 | 171 | 302 | 539 | 955 | 1694 | 3011 | 5343 | 9494

I used the following C program to generate these :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TERM 17
int main()
{
    /* code */
    int a[20]={1,1,2,3,5};

    int i=5;

    while(i <= TERM)
    {
        if((i-10) >= 0)
        {
            a[i]=a[i-1] + a[i-2] + 2*a[i-5] + 2*a[i-10];
        }
        else
        {
            a[i]=a[i-1] + a[i-2] + 2*a[i-5];
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j<= TERM; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d | ",a[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```