# recurrence relalation in Kenneth Rosen's book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I saw a question in Kenneth Rosen's Discrete math book in chapter $8.1$ , question $3$. There is an answer for it in stack exchange such that [Recurrence relation question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604977/recurrence-relation-question)

My question is as to part a , i think that OP's answer is true in given link , but  answer key is different , it says that the answer is $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2a_{n-5}+2a_{n-10}+2a_{n-20}+2a_{n-50}+2a_{n-100}$

Which answer is true ? Am i missing anything ?

Comment: For the benefit of the people who don't have access to the book: what's the *exact* formulation of the problem, and what does the key *exactly* say? Could be that it is a typo in the key, or could be that the problem in the book is slightly different from the one in the linked MSE question.

Comment: You are correct, and the answer key is wrong.